# Checking if data exists in Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, express, postgresql-9.5

I have a web app that sends data to a postgres database upon submission, I'm still new to both express and Postgres so there are probably better ways of doing what I'm trying to. I wanted to add another layer to this and have a sort of validation where if the data(either the email or the ip) already exist in the table the user would be booted out and not allowed to proceed. I've tried using NOT EXIST but kept getting either syntax errors or "there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification". What can I do to check the database?

```
DbConnectionManager.pool.query(`INSERT INTO ${Table.Test} (${Table.Email}, ${Table.IP}) VALUES ($1,$2), NOT EXISTS(SELECT * ${Table.Test} WHERE ${Table.Email} = ${Table.Email})`,
    [email, ip],
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    });
```

This is the function that sends the input data to the database, the function works if I remove NOT EXISTS.

Comment: If you get "*there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification*" this means exactly what it says. In order to use ON CONFLICT you have to create a unique constraint (or index) on the columns that you specify in the ON CONFLICT clause.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I've managed to fix the problem